# Error on Cast actvitiy

Tags: android, xml

```
java.lang.**ClassCastException:** com....activity.FriendsFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

I am unable to figure out this error in manifest xml file. How can i solve this issue?

Android_manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.pesfinal" >    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.HomeFragment" />    
        <!-- Friends Activity -->
        <activity android:name=".activity.FriendsFragment" />    
        <!-- Messages Activity -->
        <activity android:name=".activity.MessagesFragment" />    
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

Comment: Apologize it extends the Fragment

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to declare `Fragments` in your `AndroidManifest` only `Activity` classes.

Comment: i have now i have changed the Fragments to Activity classes but the error remain same.